# QTableWidget find a row through userdata

Tags: qt, find, row, qtablewidget, user-data

QTableWidget have a method to search for a row with user data?

Something like:

```
//set user data
row->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, "ID001");

//find row by user data
int rowIndex = table->findByData("ID001");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QAbstractItemModel::match()`

```
QAbstractItemModel *model = table->model();
QModelIndexList matches = model->match( model->index(0,0), Qt::UserRole, "ID001" )

foreach( const QModelIndex &index, matches )
{
    QTableWidgetItem *item = table->item( index.row(), index.column() )
    // Do something with your new-found item ...
}
```